How to determine if a limit is indepedent in an iterated integral
Below is a section of a book about convulution and fourier transform where it tries to derive the definition of convulution.
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{-2\pi ist}g(t) dt \int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{-2\pi isx}f(x) dx
=
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{-2\pi is(t+x)} g(t) dt\right) f(x) dx
\end{equation}
Let u = t + x
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{-2\pi is(t+x)} g(t) dt\right) f(x) dx
=
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{-2\pi isu} g(u-x) du\right) f(x) dx
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{-2\pi isu} g(u-x) du\right) f(x) dx
=
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}e^{-2\pi isu}\left(\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}  g(u-x) f(x) dx\right) du 
\end{equation}
For the first two part, I understand that since dt and dx are independent to each other, so that the two integrals at the beginning can be merged into one single iterated itergral.
After that the author let u = x + t, supposedly making u a dependent variable to x and t.
But at the last step, I don't understand why the exponential factor
\begin{equation}
e^{-2{\pi}isu}
\end{equation}
can be directly taken out from the inner integral of dx as if u is independent to x.
Is there anything I have misunderstood in iterated integral? Thank you.
Directly from the book

please either embed the photo in your question or use mathjax to rewrite the relevant parts from the picture

@YvesDaoust Why is u independent to x if the definition is given as u = x + t. Can you explain a bit for me. Thx.

@YvesDaoust t+ 5? Sorry I still don't get it.

@YvesDaoust It depends on t?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
